# Build Xml with Groovy

Tags: xml, serialization, groovy, streamingmarkupbuilder

I need to remove "tei:" from each tag. My original xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?oxygenRNGSchema="http://www.teic.org/release/xml/tei/custom/schema/relaxng/tei_all.rn"type="xml"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="jerome-html-proof.xsl"?>
<TEI
  xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"
  xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
  <teiHeader>
    <fileDesc>
      <titleStmt>
        <title>Chronicles (Latin working edition, based on Helm)</title>
        <author>Jerome</author>
      </titleStmt>
      <publicationStmt>
        <p>Unpublished</p>
      </publicationStmt>
      <sourceDesc>
        <p>PD online text from http://www.tertullian.org/fathers/index.htm#jeromechronicle, entitled
          "Jerome, Chronicle (2005)" and based on pages of Helm's edition indicated in milestone
          elements. </p>
        <p>Source page includes note, "This text was transcribed by JMB. All material on this page
          is in the public domain - copy freely." </p>
      </sourceDesc>
    </fileDesc>
  </teiHeader>
  <text>
    <body>
      <div
        n="preface"
        type="prefatory"> </div>
<table>    
<row role="header">
            <cell ana="abraham"/>
            <cell ana="assyrians">Regnum Assyriorum</cell>
            <cell ana="sacred-history"/>
            <cell ana="hebrews"> Hebraeorum gentis exordium</cell>
            <cell ana="sicyonians"> Regnum Sicyoniorum</cell>
            <cell ana="gentile-history"/>
            <cell ana="egyptians"> Regnum Aegyptiorum</cell>
            <cell ana="adbc"> BC</cell>
</row>   
<row role="regnal">
            <cell/>
            <cell/>
            <cell/>
            <cell/>
            <cell>Sicyoniorum III, TELCHIN, annis XX.</cell>
</row>
<row>
            <cell/>
            <cell>15</cell>
            <cell/>
            <cell>25</cell>
            <cell>1</cell>
            <cell/>
            <cell>25</cell>
            <cell>1992</cell>
</row>
</table>
</body>
</text>
</TEI>
```

When I run my script, I get the same output but with "tei:" in each tag:

```
<tei:TEI> 
<tei:text> 
<tei:body> 
<tei:div>
<tei:row role="header">...........
```

I'm trying to add a value to each row that is not used as a header and does not mark a change in ruler. My code is:

```
    import groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder
    import groovy.xml.XmlUtil

    def TEI = new XmlSlurper().parse(new File('file.xml'))
    def jeromeRow = new File("file-row.xml")
    def x = 0 


    for (row in TEI.text.body.div.table.row) {
    if (row.@role != 'regnal' && row.@role != 'header'){
    x = x + 1
    row.@n = 'r' + x 
    }
    }

def outputBuilder = new StreamingMarkupBuilder()
String result = outputBuilder.bind{ mkp.yield TEI }
jeromeRow << XmlUtil.serialize(result)
```

How do I prevent my script from making this unwanted change to my xml file.

Comment: Can you paste actual input and output? There's no role attribute or n attribute in what you've shown

Comment: The actual input and output is almost 35,000 lines. I hope this gives you a better idea of what I'm looking at. Thanks.

Comment: that input will not give a `tei:` prefix you're seeing...  do you have a better example? Maybe one that exhibits the problem you describe when run through the code in the question? (the code in the question will do nothing at present, as `TEI.text.body.div.table.row` contains nothing due to the `table` clause)

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct except for the non existing 'table'. When I run the following in groovyConsole, it looks just fine:

```
import groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil
def xmlText = """<TEI> 
<text> 
<body> 
<div>
<row role="header">
            <cell ana="abraham"/>
            <cell ana="assyrians">Regnum Assyriorum</cell>
            <cell ana="sacred-history"/>
            <cell ana="hebrews"> Hebraeorum gentis exordium</cell>
            <cell ana="sicyonians"> Regnum Sicyoniorum</cell>
            <cell ana="gentile-history"/>
            <cell ana="egyptians"> Regnum Aegyptiorum</cell>
            <cell ana="adbc"> BC</cell>
</row>   
<row role="regnal">
            <cell/>
            <cell/>
            <cell/>
            <cell/>
            <cell>Sicyoniorum III, TELCHIN, annis XX.</cell>
</row>
<row>
            <cell/>
            <cell>15</cell>
            <cell/>
            <cell>25</cell>
            <cell>1</cell>
            <cell/>
            <cell>25</cell>
            <cell>1992</cell>
</row>
</div>
</body>
</text>
</TEI>"""

def TEI = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xmlText)
def x=1
for (row in TEI.text.body.div.row) {
    if (row.@role != 'regnal' && row.@role != 'header'){
      row.@n = 'r' + x++
    }
}
def outputBuilder = new StreamingMarkupBuilder()
String result = outputBuilder.bind{ mkp.yield TEI }

println XmlUtil.serialize(result)
```

Looking at your code again, I see that you at the end APPEND data to the end of the file.

```
jeromeRow << XmlUtil.serialize(result)
```

Could it be that you for some reason (in code not submitted) are appending empty data into an already incorrect file?

Comment: As I commented above, there's something missing from this question

Comment: Tim is right. I did leave out the <table> element. I was just trying to avoid putting thousands of lines in the question and that one slipped by me.  I ran your script Joachim and I still came up with the same problem. Every element tag has "tei:" added to it. But I'll add the headings of my xml file in an edit.

Comment: @mpk that is interesting, in my versions it does not. So I assume it is a version problem. My versions:

    "Groovy Version: 2.4.5 JVM: 1.8.0_65 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Linux"   . 

I am running the code in groovyConsole

Comment: I'm using 2.4.5 but running the code in my terminal on OSX. I tried to run the code from groovyConsole, moved my files around, but couldn't get the code to find the files. I'll play with it some more. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you change

```
def TEI = new XmlSlurper().parse(new File('file.xml'))
```

to

```
def TEI = new XmlSlurper(false, false).parse(new File('file.xml'))
```

It turns off validation and namespace handling in the slurper and you should get the expected result

Comment: don't forget to give credits to tim for solving your issue